# Why Maven can not read properties from props file?

Tags: java, maven

In project I have file `src/main/resources/build.properties` and I want to read database props from it using Maven.
In file I have these params:

```
flyway.url
flyway.user
flyway.password
flyway.schemas
```

In POM file I added:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>read properties on clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/build.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>read properties on install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/build.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I'm using Flyway and I added:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flyway.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${flyway.url}</url>
                    <user>${flyway.user}</user>
                    <password>${flyway.password}</password>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>${flyway.schemas}</schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                        <version>${maria.db.java.client.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

So, it can not define database url and user. Two questions regarding to this case:

1. What I'm doing wrong?Why it does not see my properties?
2. Is it possible to work with .env files using this properties-plugin?

Comment: Why do you use an old alpha version of the plugin? Does it still fail when using version 1.1.0?

Comment: You have to be sure of the order of the phases where the goals are executed. If multiple executions have the same phase, the order on the POM is relevant. The install phase is quite late, so if the flyway happens before, perhaps the properties will not be loaded at that time.

Comment: @MJG tried 1.1.0 version - same thing

Comment: @MJG remained  just one phase - validate. no progress, tried also initialize, but no success